# Service is being recreated each time the activity resumes

Tags: android, service

I am in quite a tough predicament here as I have an activity that starts a service which runs a countdown timer. Each time the activity is resumed, the service starts another countdown timer. I looked up services and it has method which is called on once throughout the service and is called onCreate. The only issue with that is I am receiving time values from the activity through intents which is retrieved during onStartCommand. onCreate is called before onStartCommand meaning I cannot retrieve those values and plug them into onCreate. Is there a way I can put values from onStartCommand to onCreate. The following code shows my problem.

```
TextView timeTextView;
int data;


public  String hms;
public CountDownAct countDownAct;
public CountDownTime countDownTimer;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;

}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

     //I need the CountDownTimer to start here in order to prevent a new countdown timer from being created each time the activity is resumed.`             
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTime(data,1000 );
    countDownTimer.start();

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
  //the time data is being retrieved here
  data = intent.getIntExtra("the", 0);

    return START_STICKY;


}

@Override
public boolean stopService(Intent name) {

    Log.i("CountDownService", "Stop Service");
    return super.stopService(name);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    countDownTimer.cancel();

}
```

### Starting the Service

```
useService = new Intent(CountDownAct.this, CountDownService.class);
        useService.putExtra("the", actualTimeFiniliazedInMilliSeconds);

        startService(useService);
```

Comment: need code of the activity starting the service. The whole code is not needed. Just the part where you start the service

Comment: are you destroying the activity while the timer is running? that was the problem I was facing, my activity was destroyed and so the service too, as I called the stopService in my onDestroy of my activity

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SharedPreference` to store `actualTimeFiniliazedInMilliSeconds`. This can be retrived from service class :

```
useService = new Intent(CountDownAct.this, CountDownService.class);

SharedPreference mShared = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreference("myShared",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = mShared.edit();
mEditor.putInt("data",actualTimeFiniliazedInMilliSeconds).commit();

startService(useService);
```

Retriving :

```
SharedPreference mShared = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreference("myShared",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
countDownTimer = new CountDownTime(mShared.getInt("data",0),1000);
countDownTimer.start();
```

Comment: this could work, but why would the service be recreated? Correct me if I'm wrong, Isn't service a singleton? So, once created, its onCreate should not be called, right?

Comment: Your service is `Sticky` because you are returning `START_STICKY` from `onStartCommand()`.. Making it `START_NOT_STICKY` will not recreate service

Comment: firstly, not my question! :P just wanted to know. Secondly, i read the documentation, and it says, "if this service's process is killed while it is started" meaning, this would make sense only if the service was killed while it was running. Which is not happening in this case? We dont kill the service, do we?

Comment: Your `onCreate()` is called multiple times that means in your code, service class instance is initialized again and again... I faced similar issue in which service was re-created by system.. I fixed this by making my service **NOT_STICKY**..